# Google Chrome device frame is not visible when turned on

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I know my question is out of topic, but I will ask anyway. Because I need an answer, I also asked this on Quora.

From this [site](https://winaero.com/blog/make-screenshot-of-web-page-with-device-frame-in-chrome/) it shows how to enable the frame.

I want to take a screen shot / even full screen shot of my web app for showcase / use it for reporting. I used `Chrome` for this.

In the developer's tool there is this option to hide and show the `Device Frame`. Yet I didn't see it.

[image: sample]

As you can see, there is an overflow menu from the right - `hide device frame`. I already enabled it.

I take a sample screen shot from Angular Material page. As you can see there is no device frame wrapping the web app. Yet I enable the device frame. :(

[image: angularMaterial]

I thought it will be visible the device frame once the screen shot is done. But what I see is what I get.

Is this a bug? Is there any extension that can perform this operation?

Comment: See https://crbug.com/838829. Only some of the devices currently have frames.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I added all the `Device` type from the settings, and these are the ones with a frame

My `Chrome version:  67.0.3396.87`

---

**PHONE**

`Iphone 5/SE` - With orientation but no keyboard & toolbar offered.

`Iphone 6/7/8` - With orientation but no keyboard & toolbar offered.

`Iphone 6/7/8 Plus` - With orientation but no keyboard & toolbar offered.

`Nexus 5` - **No Frame wrapping**, only navigation and status bar. Offers layout orientation keyboard and toolbar (from Chrome Browser)

`Nexus 5x` - **Offers layout orientation keyboard and toolbar (from Chrome Browser)**

`Nexus 6P` - With orientation but no keyboard & toolbar offered.

---

**TABLET**

`Ipad` - With orientation but no keyboard & toolbar offered.

---

**LAPTOP**

None

---

The rest won't work.

*(I've noticed that, it seems that the frame will be downloaded if you are connected to the internet. Especially those mention above)*

In this case I was in airplane mode in my laptop and already have the frame, but not the additional components like keyboard and toolbar from Chrome Browser.

[image: airplane]

I turn the network on. And select again the option

[image: network]

---

**Custom Device**
You can add your own custom device, but I doubt the frame will only included base on the brand you choose.

[image: Custom Device]

[Device Mode - Google Web Dev](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode)

---

In Opera, same as Chrome Developers tool. In Edge. There is no device frame display option.

Comment: I wonder why Google's own devices (of Pixel family) don't have frames in Chrome...

Comment: Can we add new custom device frames?

Comment: @lady - it seems you can. :) , but the phone image, I doubt it. 

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode

Comment: You are right. Turned on my internet and it suddenly appeared!

Answer (score 13):

As of Chrome v97.0.4692.71 (Win10):

Devices with frames:

- Moto G4
- Nexus 5X
- Nexus 6P
- Nest Hub
- Nest Hub Max
- iPhone 5/SE
- iPhone 6/7/8
- iPhone 6/7/8 Plus
- iPad

Devices with toolbars (no frame):

- Nexus 5

Test procedure used:

1. Toggle Device Toolbar (<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) to show device mode
2. Click the `⋮` menu on the device toolbar to "Show device frame"
3. Click the device list menu to select "Edit..."
4. Manually select every option on the Devices list on the dev panel (since there is no Select All option)
5. Click the device list menu to set the view to the top-most option
6. Manually start deselecting each device on the dev panel, starting from the top. When the current selection is deselected, the view automatically shifts to the next device on the list.
7. Reselect the devices I actually want