# device frame is not visible even when I enable it in chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, frontend, google-chrome-devtools

I can't see any frames! I tried to disable and re-enable it but the result was the same btw I'm new and maybe it's a silly question to ask! sorry.

I have toggled between all the options but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Only one that I can find with a device frame is iPhone 6/7/8 (must be added from device list).

Answer (score 0):

Not all device frames are available:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode

As it says in the link:
"Note: If you don't see a device frame for a particular device, it probably means that DevTools just doesn't have art for that specific option."

See this post for specifics about what frames are available:
[Google Chrome device frame is not visible when turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50975043/google-chrome-device-frame-is-not-visible-when-turned-on)